# Remove end of Line Comma from a Azure data lake store File

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-lake

I need some inputs on file processing in Azure Data lake storage using Power Shell.

I have a pipe Delimited input file in my ADLS Gen 1 Account.

The File content looks like below

```
1|2|3|a,b,
3|4|5|d,h,
```

I am able to remove last comma using powershell in my Local PC using below code

```
Get-Content $file_name | ForEach-Object {$_.TrimEnd(",")  }
```

But when i run the same query against the same file in Azure Data lake Storage Gen 1 Account nothing happen to the data . The code i am using is

```
Get-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItemContent -Account $accountName -Path $myrootdir/path/test.csv| ForEach-Object {$_.TrimEnd( ",")  }
```

One observation i have is that ForEach-Object is returning only once. That is if i print hello inside ForEach-Object loop it prints only one. But i verified that there is no new line problem by running -Head and -Tail command. I am attaching a screenshot for the same.

Can you please help me to understand what i am doing wrong here and any alternative to remove last comma in each line.

[image: Compare behavior between Local and ADLS]

Comment: what's the returned type when use `Get-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItemContent`? string or array?

Comment: Hello Ivan, As per the documentation it is a Byte or a string. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datalakestore/get-azurermdatalakestoreitemcontent?view=azurermps-6.13.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can modify the store item directly via powershell.

The `Get-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItemContent` just gets the content. (Based on my experience, if it allows you to do that, it should be a command like `Set-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItemContent` or`Update-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItemContent`)

The workaround is to [export the file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datalakestore/export-azurermdatalakestoreitem?view=azurermps-6.13.0) -> modify it in local -> [import it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datalakestore/import-azurermdatalakestoreitem?view=azurermps-6.13.0) again.

**Update**:

If I do not misunderstand your question, try the command below.

```
((Get-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItemContent -AccountName "joydatalake1" -Path "/sss/test.csv").ToString() -split("`r")).Trim() | ForEach-Object {$_.TrimEnd(",")}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Joy, Thank you for your comments. if you see my code , i have not tried to Write any contents as i need to manipulate my data first . My idea was to pass the output of Get-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItemContent  which i believe is a Object to Set-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItemContent . But here the problem is arising in the first part of file manipulation itself. The work around of export and import is not a practical solution as this need to be part of an automated workflow.

Comment: Hi Joy,  Thank You for your suggestion, it worked. I have accepted the solution. If you would be kind enough to add some explanation it will be very helpful.

Comment: @NaveenVenugopal The output of the command is only one object, so if you use foreach-object, it will just remove the last comma. In local, the output is two objects.

Comment: Joy is right. When use `Get-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItemContent`, it returns a string, you can iterate only once(for `get-content`, it returns array, so you can iterate all of items in it).

Comment: @JoyWang@IvanYang Apologies for another question.  When i pass the output of your command to a variable and pass it to NewAzureRmDataLakeStoreItem i am getting error  "Invalid content passed in" . Any inputs on how to make it work. $data= Your command
 $data.GetType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name    BaseType
-------- -------- ----             --------
True     True     Object[]    System.Array
> New-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem  -Account $account -path $myrootdir/test_output.txt -Value $data
Invalid content passed in. Only byte[] and string content is supported.

Comment: @NaveenVenugopal Hi, Naveen, for the stackoverflow policy, could you post it as another question? It will be better for others to refer to it.

Comment: @JoyWang . Thanks . Here is the new Thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53533224/writing-output-of-string-manipulation-to-azure-data-lake-store-item